# How to display payment type after entering card number in angular

Tags: angular

Hi I am doing project in angular6. I am designing form. In that 2 input fields are there, one is card_no and other on is type_of_card. When we type card no in card_no input field, after clicking on enter,It should display type of card inside type_of_card input field, depending on card number. How to achieve this in angular. Any help please!!!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

4 - Visa /
 5 - MasterCard /
    6 - Discover Card

4, 5 & 6 are first digit of you card.

Now that you know this, after they press enter, read the first elem of the card number & display the respective card type.

How to code this you ask,

```
(keydown.enter)="youFuncToCheck(card_number)"

function youFuncToCheck(card_number){
  ref_obj = {
    "4" : "Visa"
    "5" : "MasterCard"
    "6" : "Discover Card"

  }
  first_digit = card_number[0]
  if(first_digit in ref_obj){
      return ref_obj[first_digit]
    }

   else{
    // raise error maybe
    }
```